# DataGridView throws System.invalidoperationException only with one file

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` that i initialize in the constructor of the form by `reading` the cells from a file `Widerstand.txt`. This works fine.

```
   Public Sub New()

        ' Dieser Aufruf ist für den Designer erforderlich.
        InitializeComponent()

        Widerstand.widerstandEinlesen()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To Widerstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Widerstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(i)
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Widerstand.wertepaarWiderstand.Item(i)
        Next


    End Sub
```

When I click on a button i want to add all the cells of the datagridview to the file, in case something has changed. This is how i tried to do it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Widerstand.widerstandEintragen()
 End Sub

Shared Sub widerstandEintragen()
        Dim datei As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\Widerstand\Widerstand.txt", FileMode.Open)
        Dim schreiber As New StreamWriter(datei)
        For i = 0 To FormWiderstand.DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            schreiber.WriteLine(FormWiderstand.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & ";" & vbTab & FormWiderstand.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & ";")
        Next
        schreiber.Close()
        datei.Close()
    End Sub
```

But I get a `System.invalidoperationException` in the line 
  `For i = 0 To FormWiderstand.DataGridView1.RowCount - 2`. 
The strange thing is, that if i change the file to Widerstandblabla.txt it works.

Can anyone help me? Thx!

Edit: here is the full code of the classes that are used causing this problem.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Widerstand
    Public Shared widerstand As New List(Of Double)
    Public Shared wertepaarGeschwindigkeit As New List(Of Double)
    Public Shared wertepaarWiderstand As New List(Of Double)

    Shared Sub widerstandEinlesen()
        widerstand.Clear()
        wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Clear()
        wertepaarWiderstand.Clear()
        Dim datei As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\Widerstand\Widerstand.txt", FileMode.Open)
        Dim leser As New StreamReader(datei)
        Dim zeile As String
        Dim werte() As String
        Dim wertepaarMaxGeschwindigkeit As Double

        While leser.Peek <> -1
            zeile = leser.ReadLine
            werte = zeile.Split(";")
            wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Add(werte(0))
            wertepaarWiderstand.Add(werte(1))
            If werte(0) > wertepaarMaxGeschwindigkeit Then
                wertepaarMaxGeschwindigkeit = werte(0)
            End If
        End While
        leser.Close()
        datei.Close()
        For i = 0 To wertepaarMaxGeschwindigkeit
            For j = 0 To wertepaarWiderstand.Count - 1
                If wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(j) >= i Then
                    Dim r0, r1, v0, v1 As Double
                    If j <> 0 Then
                        r0 = wertepaarWiderstand.Item(j - 1)
                        v0 = wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(j - 1)
                    Else
                        r0 = 0
                        v0 = 0
                    End If
                    r1 = wertepaarWiderstand.Item(j)
                    v1 = wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(j)
                    If v1 - v0 <> 0 Then
                        widerstand.Add(r0 + (r1 - r0) / (v1 - v0) * (i - v0))
                    Else
                        widerstand.Add(0)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Shared Sub widerstandEintragen(tabelle As DataGridView)
        Dim datei As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\Widerstand\Widerstand.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim schreiber As New StreamWriter(datei)
        MsgBox(tabelle.RowCount)
        For i = 0 To tabelle.RowCount - 1
            schreiber.WriteLine(tabelle.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & ";" & vbTab & tabelle.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & ";")
        Next
        schreiber.Close()
        datei.Close()
    End Sub
End Class





Public Class FormWiderstand

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim neuesFenster As New FormHauptseite
        neuesFenster.Show()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Widerstand.widerstandEintragen(Me.DataGridView1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormWiderstand_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Widerstand.widerstandEinlesen()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To Widerstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Widerstand.wertepaarGeschwindigkeit.Item(i)
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Widerstand.wertepaarWiderstand.Item(i)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: First things first, that code should be in the Load event handler, not the constructor.

Comment: Thx, I copied the code to the load handler. It works also, so I will keep doing it like this. Still the other mistake appears. thx!

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you refer to just `DataGridView1`, indicating that the grid is on the current instance.  In the second code snippet, you use `FormWiderstand.DataGridView1`, which appears to be referring to a grid on the default instance rather than the current instance.  This is a fine example of why you should **always** be consistent.  If you want to refer to the same grid from code in the same form then refer to it the same way.  Personally, I like to use `Me` to refer to the current instance explicitly because it makes things clearer.

Comment: This is because the first snippet belongs to the class FormWiderstand and the secound one to the class Widerstand. Thats why I cant use "Me". Am I right? Thx in advance!!

Comment: Then your post is confusing because you appear to have two methods together that are actually in different code files and types.  I think that the issue is still quite possibly the fact that you're using the default instance in one place and not another.  Is the instance of `FormWiderstand` that you displayed in the first place the default instance of that type?  If you don;t know what a default instance is then read this: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html

Comment: Yes, that was my first big mistake. I managed to solve this. I do now work with the actual datagrid, not with the default one anymore. But the exception, that the file is still in use still appears. I will post a little more code, maybe u will find my mistake! Thx